# Storing JSON data into MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, json

I am having a JSON file with multiple and multi-level data. 
Now I want to store this data into MySQL database. 
I searched many links but didn't suit to my data and none of it helped me.

My JSON data: http://fiddle.jshell.net/4QNYk/

I am new to JSON and Java. Please help me out.

Comment: I dont think there's anything wrong with storing it as text?

Comment: Take data type as text and store whole response in database

Comment: Use Postgres :) It has `json` data type and is able to both store and query json data effectively. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What's_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.2#JSON_datatype (more effectively than MongoDB).

Comment: if u just want to store as it is and retrieve JSON text as it is on query then datatype of TEXT will do !!
if u want to query on this JSON data in future then use MongoDB Database,

Comment: Could you please help me how to store it as a text in database.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you want to do later with the JSON, storing it as a normal text seems to be the best idea on MySQL at the moment. Other DBMS like PostgreSQL are having some datatype for JSON -- but assuming you having you application magic at Java-side and not wanting to start fuzzying around with the JSON on database layer, text is totally fine.

Of course, if you want to search inside the JSON it's maybe not the best way of storing them. But as mentioned in the comments, there are other DBMS are better choice.

Comment: hi @frlan Thanks for the quick response. Can you please help me how to store it as a normal text in MySQL.

Comment: No clue about Java at this point. Create a text field on you MySQL and ensure you JSON object is transfered to varchar/string/* before sending to database.